# How can I reduce complexity of contour by cv2 python?

Tags: python, opencv

I have some contour image and I want to obtain more simple contour. For example if there is some litle curves such wool of animal or beard of man than I would like to change it woth simple line. For instance on this image from first picture I want to get second. I use cv2 in it. [image]

Comment: Why would the wool pattern be removed but the individual 'toes' remain?

Comment: They could be removed either, I have just wanted to illustrate the idea - I want to exclude 'complex' lines and set simple lines.

Comment: What you could do is get the contour and then randomly sample points from the contour and draw lines between said points

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV gives you very basic control with the [`ContourApproximationModes`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga4303f45752694956374734a03c54d5ff) enum that you pass to the [`findContours()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0) function:

> `CHAIN_APPROX_NONE`
> stores absolutely all the contour points. That is, any 2 subsequent points `(x1,y1)` and `(x2,y2)` of the contour will be either horizontal, vertical or diagonal neighbors, that is, `max(abs(x1-x2),abs(y2-y1))==1`.
>
> `CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE`
> compresses horizontal, vertical, and diagonal segments and leaves only their end points.
> For example, an up-right rectangular contour is encoded with 4 points.
>
> `CHAIN_APPROX_TC89_L1`
> applies one of the flavors of the Teh-Chin chain approximation algorithm `[241]`
>
> `CHAIN_APPROX_TC89_KCOS`
> applies one of the flavors of the Teh-Chin chain approximation algorithm `[241]`